# My game is crashing. The crash report is attached

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, crash-reports

I uploaded a game to the play store and the game is sometimes crashing. The reason given by the google crash report is this:

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault <<<
```

backtrace:

```
  #00  pc 000000000007ba60  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 00000000004ffec4  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #02  pc 00000000005003d4  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #03  pc 0000000000164384  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #04  pc 0000000000161e00  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #05  pc 00000000001638bc  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #06  pc 000000000025cc50  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #07  pc 0000000000636278  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #08  pc 0000000000319eac  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #09  pc 0000000000445424  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #10  pc 00000000005e7570  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #11  pc 00000000005ef818  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #12  pc 00000000005e6d00  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #13  pc 000000000026b790  /data/app/com.DefaultCompany.GravitysFault-MPZSN7QrIjprfkcFvzErQA==/lib/arm64/libunity.so
  #14  pc 0000000000090120  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #15  pc 0000000000023968  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

Can someone please tell me what it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libc.so is an Android system library, and you might be able to learn more about diagnosing libc issues here: https://source.android.com/devices/tech/debug/native-crash. You could also use ndk-stack to try to get more data out of this stacktrace: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack